# image overlay on hover javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

i am trying to display additional info over an image by using two overlay images.
on mouse hover overlay1 will be displayed at the top left corner of the main-image and overlay2 will be at bottom right..

when i try this to do on a single image it works fine..
but as i get on to do it on gallery of images the overlay images displays at the top-left and bottom-right section of the screen..

i want the images to be overlay-ed on the respective main-images..

here is the html-

```
<div id="WhizIt">
<div id="btpanelexsmall">
<h3>Heading1</h3>

<ul >
<li><a href=""><img src="image/" class="wit"/><img class="overlay"  
src="image/top-left.jpg"/>
<img class="overly" src="image/bottom-right.jpg"/></a></li>

<li><a href=""><img src="images/" class="wit" /><img class="overlay"  
src="image/top-left.jpg"/>
<img class="overly" src="image/bottom-right.jpg"/></a></li>

<li><a href=""><img src="images/" class="wit" /><img class="overlay"  
src="image/top-left.jpg"/>
<img class="overly" src="image/bottom-right.jpg"/></a></li>

<li><a href=""><img src="images/" class="wit" /><img class="overlay"  
src="image/top-left.jpg"/>
<img class="overly" src="image/bottom-right.jpg"/></a></li>

<li><a href=""><img src="images/" class="wit" /><img class="overlay"  
src="image/top-left.jpg"/>
<img class="overly" src="image/bottom-right.jpg"/></a></li>

<li><a href=""><img src="images/" class="wit" /><img class="overlay"  
src="image/top-left.jpg"/>
<img class="overly" src="image/bottom-right.jpg"/></a></li>
</ul><br>

<ul>
<li><a href=""><img src="images/" class="wit" /><img class="overlay"  
src="image/top-left.jpg"/>
<img class="overly" src="image/bottom-right.jpg"/></a></li>

<li><a href=""><img src="images/" class="wit" /><img class="overlay"  
src="image/top-left.jpg"/>
<img class="overly" src="image/bottom-right.jpg"/></a></li>

<li><a href=""><img src="images/" class="wit" /><img class="overlay"  
src="image/top-left.jpg"/>
<img class="overly" src="image/bottom-right.jpg"/></a></li>

<li><a href=""><img src="images/" class="wit" /><img class="overlay"  
src="image/top-left.jpg"/>
<img class="overly" src="image/bottom-right.jpg"/></a></li>

<li><a href=""><img src="images/" class="wit" /><img class="overlay"  
src="image/top-left.jpg"/>
<img class="overly" src="image/bottom-right.jpg"/></a></li>

<li><a href=""><img src="images/arrow1.jpg" class="wit" /><img class="overlay"  
src="image/top-left.jpg"/>
<img class="overly" src="image/bottom-right.jpg"/></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

the script is-

```
<script src="js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('ul li').mouseenter(function() {
                $(this).find(".overlay").show();
                $(this).find(".overly").show();
            });
            $('ul li').mouseleave(function() {
                $(this).find(".overlay").hide();
                $(this).find(".overly").hide();
            });
        });
</script>
```

and the css-

```
.WhizIt li{position:relative;
float:left;
padding-left:5px;
list-style:none;}


.overlay 
{
position:absolute;
height:50px;
width:150px;
top:0;
left:0;
display:none;}



.overly 
{
 position:absolute;
 height:50px;
 width:150px;
 bottom:0;
 right:0; 
display:none;}

 #btpanelexsmall{height:390px;
 margin:0px;
 padding:0px;
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
border-radius: 10px; /* future proofing */
border:2px solid yellow;
background: #f0f0f0;}
```

i have many galleries on my page!!
thanks in advance

Comment: I think you have this same question before also! - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19830285/an-effect-onto-gallery-of-images-using-same-javascript/19830537#19830537

Comment: @SujataChanda yes and do remember you helping me to get the solution.. but when i use the script now using the above html it is not working fine

Comment: What is problem that you are facing now?

Comment: @SujataChanda when i hover on the main image the overlayed images are being displayed at the corners of the whole screen not on the corners of main image

Comment: Ok. Let me look into the problem. If i can find any solution then i will post it here.

Comment: @SujataChanda pretty sure!!

Comment: Well i think the script is working correctly. In the css change `.WhizIt li` to `#WhizIt li`. I think it will work now.

Comment: @SujataChanda thanks a ton... what a silly mistake.... can you help me with one more thing?? i want the overlaying images to be appeared in rotating pattern..

Answer (score 0):

I think your 1st problem is solved. Now to give 'rotate' effect to the overlaying images use css3 animation. We can do it with jquery also but I think using css3 will be good.

For this effect, use this script:-

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
                $('ul li').mouseenter(function() {
                    $(this).find(".overlay").show().addClass('rotate');
                    $(this).find(".overly").show().addClass('rotate');
                });
                $('ul li').mouseleave(function() {
                    $(this).find(".overlay").hide().removeClass('rotate');
                    $(this).find(".overly").hide().removeClass('rotate');
                });
            });
```

Add this css:-

```
.rotate {
    -webkit-animation: rotateImg 1s linear;
    -moz-animation: rotateImg 1s linear;
    -ms-animation: rotateImg 1s linear;
    -o-animation: rotateImg 1s linear;
    animation: rotateImg 1s linear;
}

@keyframes "rotateImg" {
    50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
}

}

@-moz-keyframes "rotateImg" {
    50% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
100% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
}

}

@-webkit-keyframes "rotateImg" {
    50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
}

}

@-ms-keyframes "rotateImg" {
    50% {
    -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
100% {
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
}

}

@-o-keyframes "rotateImg" {
    50% {
    -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
100% {
    -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code:

```
<div id="WhizIt">
<div id="btpanelexsmall">
<h3>Heading1</h3>

<ul >
<li><a href=""><img class="overly_left" src="image/top-left.jpg"/></a></li>
<li><a href=""><img class="overly_left" src="image/top-left.jpg"/></a></li>
<li><a href=""><img class="overly_left" src="image/top-left.jpg"/></a></li>
<li><a href=""><img class="overly_left" src="image/top-left.jpg"/></a></li>

</ul><br>

<ul>
<li><a href=""><img class="overly" src="image/bottom-right.jpg"/></a></li>
<li><a href=""><img class="overly" src="image/bottom-right.jpg"/></a></li>
<li><a href=""><img class="overly" src="image/bottom-right.jpg"/></a></li>
<li><a href=""><img class="overly" src="image/bottom-right.jpg"/></a></li>

</ul>
</div>
</div>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('ul li').mouseenter(function() {
                $(this).find(".overlay").show();
                $(this).find(".overly_left").show();
                $(this).find(".overly").show();
            });
            $('ul li').mouseleave(function() {
                $(this).find(".overlay").hide();
                $(this).find(".overly_left").hide();
                $(this).find(".overly").hide();
            });

        });
</script>
<style>
.WhizIt li{position:relative;
float:left;
padding-left:5px;
list-style:none;}


.overlay 
{
position:absolute;
height:50px;
width:150px;
top:0;
left:0;
display:none;}

.overly_left 
{
 position:absolute;
 height:50px;
 width:50px;
 top:0;
 left:0; 
display:none;}


.overly 
{
 position:absolute;
 height:50px;
 width:50px;
 bottom:0;
 right:0; 
display:none;}

 #btpanelexsmall{height:390px;
 margin:0px;
 padding:0px;
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
border-radius: 10px; /* future proofing */
border:2px solid yellow;
background: #f0f0f0;}
</style>
```